# Unable to catch exception in Controller in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-roo, spring-data-jpa

I've a Spring MVC application with @Controller, @Service and @Repository components (all generated from Spring Roo). I'm trying to catch a ConstraintViolationException in controller but I'm not able to. I'm trying to handle all exceptions at the controller level but the problem is when I make a call to repository from my service and if an exception occurs, I'm not getting the flow inside my catch block in the controller. I'm unable to figure out why this is happening. Is this configured by Spring? Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
     public ResponseEntity<String> createFromJson(@RequestBody IndividualProviderDto individualProviderDto) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    HttpStatus httpStatus = null;

    try {
        individualProviderService.saveIndividualProvider(individualProviderDto);
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.CREATED;

    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, httpStatus);
    }
```

Service:

```
 public void saveIndividualProvider(IndividualProviderDto individualProviderDto) {
    IndividualProvider individualProvider = individualProviderDtoToIndividualProviderMapper.map(individualProviderDto);
    individualProviderRepository.save(individualProvider);
}
```

Stack:

```
2014-06-24 09:15:36,117 ["http-bio-9001"-exec-6] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'xxx@gmail.com' for key 'UK_thwi4ibpanesigdfbx3iqt0bg'
Servlet.service() for servlet [bham] in context with path [/cds] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception
.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statemen
t] with root cause
         com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'xxx@gmail.com' for key 'UK_thwi4ibpanesigdfbx3iqt0bg'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2441)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2366)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2350)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.persist(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.persist(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:369)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:105)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.save(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.bham.service.provider.IndividualProviderServiceImpl.saveIndividualProvider(IndividualProviderServiceImpl.java:82)
        at com.mycompany.bham.web.IndividualProviderController.createFromJson(IndividualProviderController.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

Comment: Can you post your code? What does the log look like when an exception occurs?

Comment: Edited my question to include code and log.

Comment: It seems to me that the exception that is thrown is a `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException`, am I wrong? Try to catch this exception instead.

Comment: Spring is probably wrapping your exception

Comment: 'sp00m' is correct. I had to catch JpaSystemException. I was looking at the wrong exception - have to be more careful when looking at the stack. Thanks you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Exception Handler of Spring http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Here an example code:

```
              @Controller
              public class ExceptionHandlingController {

                // @RequestHandler methods
                ...

                // Exception handling methods

                // Convert a predefined exception to an HTTP Status code
                @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.CONFLICT, reason="Data integrity violation")  // 409
                @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
                public void conflict() {
                  // Nothing to do
                }

                // Specify the name of a specific view that will be used to display the                   error:
                @ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class,DataAccessException.class})
                public String databaseError() {
                  // Nothing to do.  Returns the logical view name of an error page, passed to
                  // the view-resolver(s) in usual way.
                  // Note that the exception is _not_ available to this view (it is not added to
                  // the model) but see "Extending ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver" below.
                  return "databaseError";
                }

                // Total control - setup a model and return the view name yourself. Or consider
                // subclassing ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver (see below).
                @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
                public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
                  logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + exception);

                  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
                  mav.addObject("exception", exception);
                  mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
                  mav.setViewName("error");
                  return mav;
                }
              }
```